# Chooser for apostrophe-page with joinByOne

Tags: apostrophe, apostrophe-cms

I'm trying the following code blog in a definition for a Widget:

```
    {
    name: '_page',
    type: 'joinByOne',
    withType: 'apostrophe-page',
    label: 'Internal Page',
    idField: 'pageId',
  }
```

I did expect to receive kind of graphical chooser to select the specific page (e.g. like I could do it with files, images or users). But it doesn't work. I already tried a lot. But I don't get it.

Would be nice if anyone has ideas or help for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a `joinByOne` field, it will by default come loaded up with a typeahead behavior so that you can select the item to create the join to. Pages are handled the same way as other item types.

As an example, if you following the [custom widgets tutorial](http://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/getting-started/custom-widgets.html) the page join field will behave this way.